# PostgreSql: select only weekends

Tags: sql, postgresql, weekend

I have a table containing the public holidays

```
id   | description                 | date
 1   | Ferragosto and Assunzione   | 2012-08-15 00:00:00
 2   | Tutti i santi (Ognissanti)  | 2012-11-01 00:00:00
 ......
```

I want to select only the holidays occurring on the weekends (Saturday &  Sunday) with PostgreSQL.

I know there is a function called extract and isodow to extract the day of week but I don't know how to use it in my case:

```
 select extract(isodow from date '2016-12-12')
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You could use query which is similar to this one:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table
 WHERE EXTRACT(ISODOW FROM date) IN (6, 7)
```