# Query date ranges excluding weekends in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, range, date-range

I have the following postgresql table;

```
 id   |        date_slot        
------+-------------------------
 1    | [2023-02-08,2023-02-15)
 2    | [2023-02-20,2023-02-26)
 3    | [2023-02-27,2023-03-29)
```

I want to make a query that return rows contained in these ranges but exclude weekends

for example the query I made return the following but does not exclude the weekends.

```sql
SELECT * FROM table where '2023-02-11'::date <@ date_slot;
 id   |        date_slot        
------+-------------------------
 1    | [2023-02-08,2023-02-15)
```

`2023-02-11` is a weekend so it must not return a result. How can I do that?

Comment: try `SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE '2023-02-11'::date <@ date_slot
AND date_part('dow', '2023-02-11'::date) NOT IN (0, 6);`  where `date_part` filter weekend

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PostgreSql: select only weekends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47967242/postgresql-select-only-weekends)

Answer (score 1):

### Selecting workday-only `daterange`s (without weekends):

You can check what day of the week it is on the first day in the range using [`extract()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) and knowing its length from [`upper()-lower()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html#RANGE-FUNCTIONS-TABLE), determine if it'll cross a weekend: [online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/1MFQen3W)

```sql
select * 
from test_table 
where '2023-02-11'::date <@ date_slot
and extract(isodow from lower(date_slot)
                        + (not lower_inc(date_slot))::int)
  +(  (upper(date_slot) - (not upper_inc(date_slot))::int)
     -(lower(date_slot) + (not lower_inc(date_slot))::int) ) < 6 ;
```

Cases where your ranges have varying upper and lower bound inclusivity are handled by [`lower_inc()` and `upper_inc()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html#RANGE-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) - their boolean result, when cast to int, just adds or subtracts a day to account for whether it's included by the range or not.

The range is on or includes a weekend if it starts on a weekend day or continues for too long from any other day of the week:

- 4 days, if it starts on a Monday (`isodow=1`)
- 3 days, if it starts on a Tuesday (`isodow=2`)
- 2 days, if it starts on a Wednesday (`isodow=3`)
- 1 days, if it starts on a Thursday (`isodow=4`)
- 0 days, if it starts on a Friday (`isodow=5`)

This means the `isodow` of range start date and the range length cannot sum up to more than 5 for the range not to overlap a weekend.

---

You can also enumerate the dates contained by these ranges using [`generate_series()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html#FUNCTIONS-SRF-SERIES) and see if they include a Saturday (day `6`) or a Sunday (`0` as `dow`, `7` as `isodow`):

```sql
select * 
from test_table 
where '2023-02-11'::date <@ date_slot
and not exists (
  select true
  from generate_series(
          lower(date_slot) + (not lower_inc(date_slot))::int,
          upper(date_slot) - (not upper_inc(date_slot))::int,
          '1 day'::interval) as alias(d)
  where extract(isodow from d) in (6,7) );
```

---

### Selecting records based on workday-only `date`s:

[First comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75384771/query-date-ranges-excluding-weekends-in-postgresql/75385182#comment133016111_75384771) got it right

```sql
select * 
from table_with_dateranges dr, 
     table_with_dates d
where d.date <@ dr.date_slot
and extract(isodow from d.date) not in (6,7);
```